# How base package version relates to GHC version?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Since `base` contains some `GHC` modules, it looks like it may be coupled with certain GHC release. Suppose that I want to use library that depends on `base:4.8.0.0`, does it mean it requires certain GHC release and I need to upgrade GHC?

Comment: I think so. At least the major and minor versions of the `base` package (like 4.8) correspond to a particular version of GHC (like 7.10). Check out this wiki page for some older versions: https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package#Versions

Comment: Maybe you should comment about _why_ you want to do this. E.g., in your context it may be possible to infer the ghc version from something else in a more reliable way.

Comment: There is an [official table of boot library versions (including the base package)](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Libraries/VersionHistory) on GHC Trac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core library version to GHC version is a 1:N relation.

> Since base contains some GHC modules,
>   it looks like it may be coupled with certain GHC release.

`base` library is a *core library* defined as library which
[ships with GHC itself](https://wiki.haskell.org/Library_submissions).

The GHC and library versions are maintained independently but the
shipped library version changes are documented in each
[GHC release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-10-1.html#idp5879344).

[Base package haskell wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package#Versions) lists changes to shipped `base`
library version and the GHC version where changed.

> Suppose that I want to use library that depends on base:4.8.0.0,
>   does it mean it requires certain GHC release and I need to upgrade GHC?

Mostly yes. It is not recommended to update core libraries alone though
it is possible sometimes, ... by some people.

As a side note GHC does not release odd minor [versions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/version-numbering.html).

Also some libraries are defined by the haskell [reports](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellpa2.html#x20-192000II). However,
there doesn't appear any mention of libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading `base` by minor version steps might be theoretically possible sometimes. However, there is really no guarantee, and I'm not sure it's ever actually possible. Furthermore, it's hard to imagine why one might want to do so-it's not likely to be faster or easier than upgrading GHC.